# Magento2 : How can checked by default radio button estimate shipping options

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

I need default checked radio button in shipping method section on cart and checkout page. I was tried with jquery but it's not working, because its render through Json on country drop-down selection.

Anyone have any solution?

Thanks